# Calculating best option among multiple items based on score and price in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to calculate which provider is the best option to make purchases of specific items, each provider has a score and a price, if any of the other providers has a better score and the price isn’t higher by 10% I want the formula to suggest it.

Currently sorting the data (from cheapest to most expensive) and using IFs I’ve managed to compare cheapest provider with next one and so on, but I need the formula to compare each all the way up, for example:

```
Provider | Score | Price
A        | 7     | $10
B        | 9     | $20
C        | 8     | $10.5
```

As for now, my formula will suggest provider A as the best option, assuming provider B has a better score but the price is higher by 100%, what id like is the formula to suggest provider C as it has a better score and price its only 5% higher.

Any leads?

Comment: Can you add your current formula to the question?

Comment: Using current data, helper column solves the issue but it may create issue if find duplicate values,, so better [Edit] the post & add few genuine sample data with us also if any formula you have tried so far,, help us to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=(B2/MAX(B:B)+1/(C2/MIN(C:C)))-1
```

Then format the D column as percent.
Hope it will help. Best regards,
Lukas